# Google Plus, wrong Consent Screen on Android devices

Tags: android, google-plus, google-api-client

I have just configured an Android app on my Google console; inserted the Certificate fingerprint (SHA1) and the package name (as the image below shows).

In order to let the user to accept the connection with Google Plus I call this method:

```
GoogleApiClient client = GoogleApiClient.Builder(
    getApplicationContext(),
    new GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks() {...},
    new GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener() {...},
).addApi(Plus.API)
 .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN)
 .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_PROFILE)
 .setAccountName("mygoogleaccount@gmail.com")
 .build();

 client.connect();
```

After that, a consent screen appears on the screen.
The problem is that, into the consent screen, the app name and the app icon are not the ones configured on the [Developer console](https://console.developers.google.com/), but are the ones of the installed app.

The strange thing is that, once accepted the consent screen, calling this method

```
GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(getApplicationContext(), "mygoogleaccount@gmail.com", "oauth2:openid profile email");
```

I receive a token which comes from the app configured on the console.
I am sure of this because calling [this end point](https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?access_token=MY_TOKEN) and passing the received token I can see the same client id associated to the Android app on the console.

[image: The Android client id]

The final verification is done by going to the page that shows me [my Google Plus apps](https://plus.google.com/apps). Here I find the just accepted app but, SURPRISE, with the name and the icon configured on the console!

Summarizing. On my Android app I accept a consent screen with an app name and an icon which are the ones of the Android app itself (not the ones on the Google Developers Console). Once accepted the consent screen I see among the accepted Google Plus apps the app with the name and the icon which are on the Google Developers Console.

The question is: why I don't see the name and the icon of the app as configured on the Google Developers Console. (the problem is that on the same app on iOS I see the consent screen with the right name and the right icon, in Android not).